Quartz .NET how to get the scheduler using DI integration to clear the scheduler before initializing jobs and triggers
Situation
I have implemented Quartz using this DI integration example.
The configuration makes sure that when the application starts, the jobs and triggers overwrite the existing jobs and triggers.
Problem
BUT when I want to rename a job or trigger, it won't overwrite the existing record and add a new record. Thus, the same job or trigger (only with a different name) is twice in the DB.
Desired solution
If I could trigger scheduler.clear() before adding the jobs and triggers within the services.addQuartz function, that would be (in my opinion) the desired solution. But I can't seem to figure out how to do this using DI integration.

If you want to have a full refresh when the application starts why do you use persistent storage?

Because the application runs in Service Fabric. So it is possible that the application is scaled up, and then you don't want multiple applications concurrently running the same job

I found it! Getting the scheduler within the AddQuartz passing the properties, just initialized within the function like this:
services.AddQuartz(options =>
{
    options.InterruptJobsOnShutdown = false;
    options.InterruptJobsOnShutdownWithWait = true; // only when services.AddQuartzHostedService options.WaitForJobsToComplete is also true
    options.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        s.UseProperties = true;
        s.UseSqlServer(sqlServer =>
        {
            sqlServer.ConnectionString = configuration["ConnectionString"];
            sqlServer.TablePrefix = "Qrtz_";
        });
        s.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
    });

    try
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
           // Clear DB before adding the jobs and triggers
           ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(options.Properties);
           IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
           await scheduler.Clear();
           // Call shutdown to clear the configuration of the scheduler, otherwhise the DI scheduler will not be initialized
           await scheduler.Shutdown();
        }).Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
        // Do nothing, this happens when the application is starting for the first time and the tables are not created yet
    }

    if (assemblies?.Any() == true)
    {
        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> jobTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IJobExtenstions)));

            foreach (Type jobType in jobTypes)
            {
                IJobExtenstions jobInstance = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(jobType) as IJobExtenstions;
                options.AddJob(jobInstance.GetType(), jobInstance.JobKey);
                options.AddTrigger(jobInstance.TriggerConfigurator);
            }
        }
    };
});

